# Downgrade from Joomla 3.5.0-rc4 to 3.5.0

Tags: joomla

i found on my server Joomla in version 3.5.0 RC 4. 
Now i want to go back to version stable from RC4, becouse i have some problems with compatibility and upgrades.

What should i do to back to stable version of joomla?

Comment: A release candidate is usually the most stable version. What kind of issues do you have?

Comment: Please report your issues on the Joomla Github Repository!